# Error al guardar un detalle entre productos y ventas

Tags: php

estoy intentando guardar un detalle entre la tabla de ventas y productos , cuando intento guardar me genera varios errores y no logro saber cual es problema, quisiera resolver este inconveniente ya que se trata de mi proyecto final de grados y es muy importante continuar ya que lo debo entregar para finales de el mes de noviembre, muchas gracias por la atención prestada[[image: primeros tres errores[1]]

[image: errores siguientes]

1: primer error en la linea 36 del controlador de ventas
  [image: error en el metodo guaradar]

2:segundo error en ese mismo metodo

3:El tercer error se genera por un indice alparecer indefinido en este mismos metodo

4: error de sql que me dice que al parcer un parametro no esta llegando al modelo desde el controlador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, pon los textos de cada error copiando y pegando. Las imágenes a penas se ven. En la línea 36 no hay código, parece que tienes ahí un carácter BOM o algo así. ¿Por qué no borras esa línea del todo?

Answer (score 0):

El primer error dice que un objeto no debería ser convertido a entero, en la linea 36 del archivo VentasController.php, sin embargo en el screenshot que envías, en la linea 36 no hay nada. Estas seguro de estar revisando el archivo correcto?

Comment: Si  lo  mismo pienso yo, pero el problema si es en ese archivo y especifica mente en ese método en el controlador de ventas

Comment: No se si sea buena idea compartir el enlace del repositorio para que pudieran ver el código completo?

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda